# How to compare nested models built with the 'bayesglm' function from the pakage 'arm'?

Tags: bayesian, multiple-regression

I am trying to use the bayesglm function from the arm package to deal with the complete separation problem in my data as detailed previously in this thread [How to deal with perfect separation in logistic regression?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/11109/how-to-deal-with-perfect-separation-in-logistic-regression). My question is how to compare nested models (used to use anova when using non Bayesian logistic regression) to come up with the best model from a set of variables. Furthermore, need to know how to evaluate the model fit. 
Many thanks in advance